# How to skip file according to validation and continue loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote python program to read all image files inside some directory and did some calculation on each and every images like follow.

```
def predict_data():
predict_data[]
for img in tqdm(os.listdir(PREDICT_DIR)):
    path = os.path.join(PREDICT_DIR,img)
    im_gray = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    im_gray_size = cv2.resize(im_gray, (IMG_W_SIZE,IMG_H_SIZE))
    (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray_size, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    fm =cv.Laplacian(im_gray_size, cv2.CV_64F).var()
    findQualityImage(thresh,fm)
    im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray_size, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    predict_data.append([np.array(im_bw)])
return predict_data
```

Inside the loop I have added validation part it was called as `findQualityImage(thresh,fm)`. In there I checked some condition and return some messages as follow.

```
def findQualityImage(thresh,fm):
if thresh > fm : print('The input image in good quality')
else : sys.exit('The quality of the image not satisfy minimal requirement')
```

Once we find the corrected image program will exit from that point onward. But I want to skip that kind of images and continue the rest of process. How can I achieve this?. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to return a value from `findQualityImage` function that you can then check in your loop for true/false.

Something like:

```
if findQualityImage(thresh,fm):
    break
```

The break causes python to exit the loop and proceed to the line of code directly after it.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops